# Checking Particular username exits in KeyChain or not If not then store New User with password ios objcetive-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, keychain

I need to store username and password values to keychain , and next time if I want to store new username with password, if username already exists it show me message, but if user name is different it should store it.
Following is my code
I am able to store but not getting how to check for particular username.

```
+(bool)CheckValuesInKeyChainWithUsername:(NSString*)username
 {

NSDictionary* dictSearch = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:(__bridge id)(kSecClassInternetPassword),  kSecClass,  kCFBooleanTrue, kSecReturnAttributes, kCFBooleanTrue, kSecReturnData, nil];
NSDictionary* found = nil;
CFDictionaryRef foundCF;
OSStatus errOS = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef) dictSearch, (CFTypeRef*)&foundCF);
NSLog(@"%d",(int)errOS);
found = (__bridge NSDictionary*)(foundCF);
if (!found)
{
    return false;
}
return true;
}


 +(void)SaveUsername:(NSString*)user withPassword:(NSString*)pass 
 {

// Create dictionary of parameters to add
NSData* passwordData = [pass dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary* dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:(__bridge id)(kSecClassInternetPassword), kSecClass, passwordData, kSecValueData, user, kSecAttrAccount, nil];

// Try to save to keychain
OSStatus errOS = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef) dict, NULL);
NSLog(@"Error Code: %d", (int)errOS);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
+(bool)CheckUserNameExistsOrNot
{
NSDictionary* dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:(__bridge id)(kSecClassInternetPassword),  kSecClass, serviceName, kSecAttrServer, kCFBooleanTrue, kSecReturnAttributes, kCFBooleanTrue, kSecReturnData, nil];

// Look up in the keychain
CFDictionaryRef foundCF;
OSStatus err = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef) dict, (CFTypeRef*)&foundCF);
if (err == errSecItemNotFound)
{
    return  false;
}

return true;

}
+(bool)CheckIfInputsArePerfect:(NSString*)username ansPassword:(NSString*)password
{
NSDictionary* dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:(__bridge id)(kSecClassInternetPassword),  kSecClass, serviceName, kSecAttrServer, kCFBooleanTrue, kSecReturnAttributes, kCFBooleanTrue, kSecReturnData, nil];

// Look up in the keychain
NSDictionary* found = nil;
CFDictionaryRef foundCF;
OSStatus err = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef) dict, (CFTypeRef*)&foundCF);
if (err == errSecItemNotFound)
{
    return  false;
}

found = (__bridge NSDictionary*)(foundCF);

// Found
NSString* user = (NSString*) [found objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccount)];
NSString* pass = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[found objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"User Name :%@ and password %@",user,pass);
if([user isEqualToString:username] && [pass isEqualToString:password]){
    return  true;
}
return false;
 }

 +(void)RemoveKeyChain
 {
// Create dictionary of search parameters
NSDictionary* dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:(__bridge id)(kSecClassInternetPassword),  kSecClass, serviceName, kSecAttrServer, kCFBooleanTrue, kSecReturnAttributes, kCFBooleanTrue, kSecReturnData, nil];

// Remove any old values from the keychain
OSStatus err = SecItemDelete((__bridge CFDictionaryRef) dict);
NSLog(@"%d",(int)err);
}
+(void)SaveUsername:(NSString*)user withPassword:(NSString*)pass {


NSDictionary* dict ;//= [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:(__bridge id)(kSecClassInternetPassword),  kSecClass, serviceName, kSecAttrServer, kCFBooleanTrue, kSecReturnAttributes, nil];

// Remove any old values from the keychain
OSStatus err;// = SecItemDelete((__bridge CFDictionaryRef) dict);

// Create dictionary of parameters to add
NSData* passwordData = [pass dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:(__bridge id)(kSecClassInternetPassword), kSecClass, serviceName, kSecAttrServer, passwordData, kSecValueData, user, kSecAttrAccount, nil];

// Try to save to keychain
err = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef) dict, NULL);                                           
NSLog(@"Error Code: %d", (int)err);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a tested code. 
you need to set dictionaries to be mutable, also check for your case for invalid param (errOS == errSecPara) .

```
    +(bool)CheckValuesInKeyChainWithUsername:(NSString*)username
{

    NSMutableDictionary* dictSearch = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    [dictSearch setObject:(__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword
                              forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];

    [dictSearch setObject:(__bridge id)kSecMatchLimitOne forKey:(__bridge id)kSecMatchLimit];

    [dictSearch setObject:(__bridge id)kCFBooleanTrue
                              forKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnAttributes];


    [dictSearch setObject:username forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount];

    /*
    Unique string used to identify the keychain item: 
     //static const UInt8 kKeychainItemIdentifier[]    = "com.company.MyApp";


    NSData *keychainItemID = [NSData dataWithBytes:kKeychainItemIdentifier
                                            length:strlen((const char *)kKeychainItemIdentifier)];

    [dictSearch setObject:keychainItemID forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrGeneric];
     */

    NSMutableDictionary* found = nil;
    CFMutableDictionaryRef foundCF = nil;
    OSStatus errOS = noErr;
    errOS = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef) dictSearch, (CFTypeRef*)&foundCF);
    NSLog(@"%d",(int)errOS);


    if (errOS == errSecItemNotFound)
    {
        return false;

    }else if (errOS == noErr)
    {
        found = (__bridge NSMutableDictionary*)(foundCF);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I started with your code, but getting errors related to missing param (-50) also needs to use mutable dictionnary....I change your dictionnary initialization with a step by step one.

Comment: thanks a lot ! have you tested this on device? coz i dont have device .

Comment: yw, it works fine in both, please accept if it works fro you

Comment: Not working on simulator I have checked, could you help on it.

Comment: it works in both as I cited, please check if you successfully save user to keychaine, also give a feedback about error you get

Comment: For the first time when i write  e.g. test1 as username and pass1 for password and then call +(bool)CheckValuesInKeyChainWithUsername:(NSString*)username  which returns false(        NSLog(@"%d",(int)errOS===-25300 ) ,which is correct , again when I write same values and try to save it again returns false with same -25300 code, If the values are stored first time then it should return true second time, also I am checking on simulator.

Comment: Before writing to keychaine you need to check if a matching username already exist,

Comment: that is why I am calling (bool)CheckValuesInKeyChainWithUsername:(NSString*)username every time when I save it should give me true or false(true if user name is already there, false if user name is not there).

Comment: but it is returning false every time

Comment: errSecItemNotFound means that CheckValuesInKeyChainWithUsername works fine. if you recieve errSecItemNotFound all time means that it was never properly added to keychaine

Comment: Ohh is it! My code  for saving values is mentioned in my question, it would be very nice of you if you verify it.

Comment: Hi Idali any suggestion!

Comment: Hi try to review dict initialization in SaveUsername, use the one I used in my response